# How do I insert a value in edittext?(AlertDialog, Espresso)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have such a dialog and a text box, how do I automatically insert text into it?

[image]

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
...
onView(allOf(childAtPosition(
                allOf(withId(android.R.id.custom),
                        childAtPosition(
                                withClassName(`is`("android.widget.FrameLayout")),
                                0)),
                0),
                isDisplayed()))
                .perform(replaceText("а"), closeSoftKeyboard())

private fun childAtPosition(
            parentMatcher: Matcher<View>, position: Int): Matcher<View> {

        return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position $position in parent ")
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description)
            }

            public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
                val parent = view.parent
                return (parent is ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view == parent.getChildAt(position))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do it this way, but it does not always work and falls occur.

Comment: What you mean by automatically insert text? You mean default text on it?

Comment: @willywijaya replaceText("Hello world!")

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with :

```
editText.setText("Hello World")
```

or If you want to use hint :

```
editText.setHint("Hello World")
```

you can set it on xml :

```
android:hint="Hello World"
```

Comment: This is for normal EditText, I use AlertDialog.

Comment: Yes, but it is created in the code, and the identifier can not be obtained.